# javafx error after export but running in debug

Tags: javafx, export, scenebuilder

My project does not run after export, but in netbeans 8.2 working.
This happens only when load exceeding 14 images (13 images works fine). Here my code and the jarerror.
In debug netbeans and eclipse work all. 
I tried with scene builder and without, with every IDE and got same error.

<(https://postimg.org/image/wfxomlxkb/9a5ee3f5>?

```
package javafxprimoprogetto;
import java.net.URL;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class JavaFXprimoprogetto extends Application {    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {         
    Image castl = newImage("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/castle.png");
    ImageView castle = new ImageView(castl);  
    castle.setFitHeight(900.0);
    castle.setFitWidth(1600.0);
    castle.setPickOnBounds(true);
    castle.setPreserveRatio(true);

    Image warriorferm = new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/warriorfermogif.gif");
    ImageView warfermo = new ImageView(warriorferm);     

    warfermo.setFitHeight(150.0);
    warfermo.setFitWidth(200.0);
    warfermo.setLayoutX(419.0);
    warfermo.setLayoutY(339.0);
    warfermo.setPickOnBounds(true);
    warfermo.setPreserveRatio(true);

    Image slimeferm = new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/slimefermo.gif");
    ImageView slimefermo = new ImageView(slimeferm);

    slimefermo.setFitHeight(113.0);
    slimefermo.setFitWidth(187.0);
    slimefermo.setLayoutX(426.0);
    slimefermo.setLayoutY(401.0);
    slimefermo.setPickOnBounds(true);
    slimefermo.setPreserveRatio(true);
    slimefermo.setVisible(false);

    Image wormcammina_1 = new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/slime2cammina.png");
    ImageView wormcammina1 = new ImageView(wormcammina_1);

    wormcammina1.setFitHeight(150.0);
    wormcammina1.setFitWidth(200.0);
    wormcammina1.setLayoutX(20.0);
    wormcammina1.setLayoutY(20.0);
    wormcammina1.setPickOnBounds(true);
    wormcammina1.setPreserveRatio(true);
    wormcammina1.setVisible(true); 
    Imagewormcammina_2=newImage("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/slime3 copia.png");
    ImageView wormcammina2 = new ImageView(wormcammina_2);     

    wormcammina2.setFitHeight(150.0);
    wormcammina2.setFitWidth(200.0);
    wormcammina2.setLayoutX(10.0);
    wormcammina2.setLayoutY(10.0);
    wormcammina2.setPickOnBounds(true);
    wormcammina2.setPreserveRatio(true);
    wormcammina2.setVisible(true);

    Image wormcammina_3 = new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/slime4 copia.png");
    ImageView wormcammina3 = new ImageView(wormcammina_3);     

    wormcammina3.setFitHeight(150.0);
    wormcammina3.setFitWidth(200.0);
    wormcammina3.setLayoutX(30.0);
    wormcammina3.setLayoutY(30.0);
    wormcammina3.setPickOnBounds(true);
    wormcammina3.setPreserveRatio(true);
    wormcammina3.setVisible(true);

    Image wormcammina_4 = new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/slime5 copia.png");
    ImageView wormcammina4 = new ImageView(wormcammina_4);      

    wormcammina4.setFitHeight(150.0);
    wormcammina4.setFitWidth(200.0);
    wormcammina4.setLayoutX(40.0);
    wormcammina4.setLayoutY(40.0);
    wormcammina4.setPickOnBounds(true);
    wormcammina4.setPreserveRatio(true);
    wormcammina4.setVisible(true);

    Image wormcammina_5 = new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/slime5 copia.png");
    ImageView wormcammina5 = new ImageView(wormcammina_5);      

    wormcammina5.setFitHeight(150.0);
    wormcammina5.setFitWidth(200.0);
    wormcammina5.setLayoutX(70.0);
    wormcammina5.setLayoutY(70.0);
    wormcammina5.setPickOnBounds(true);
    wormcammina5.setPreserveRatio(true);
    wormcammina5.setVisible(true);

    Image wormcammina_6 = new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/slime6 copia.png");
    ImageView wormcammina6 = new ImageView(wormcammina_6);      

    wormcammina6.setFitHeight(150.0);
    wormcammina6.setFitWidth(200.0);
    wormcammina6.setLayoutX(45.0);
    wormcammina6.setLayoutY(45.0);
    wormcammina6.setPickOnBounds(true);
    wormcammina6.setPreserveRatio(true);
    wormcammina6.setVisible(true);

    Image wormcammina_7 = new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/slime7 copia.png");
    ImageView wormcammina7 = new ImageView(wormcammina_7);      

    wormcammina7.setFitHeight(150.0);
    wormcammina7.setFitWidth(200.0);
    wormcammina7.setLayoutX(50.0);
    wormcammina7.setLayoutY(50.0);
    wormcammina7.setPickOnBounds(true);
    wormcammina7.setPreserveRatio(true);
    wormcammina7.setVisible(true);

    Image wormcammina_8 = new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/slime8 copia.png");
    ImageView wormcammina8 = new ImageView(wormcammina_8);      

    wormcammina8.setFitHeight(150.0);
    wormcammina8.setFitWidth(200.0);
    wormcammina8.setLayoutX(80.0);
    wormcammina8.setLayoutY(80.0);
    wormcammina8.setPickOnBounds(true);
    wormcammina8.setPreserveRatio(true);
    wormcammina8.setVisible(true); 

    Image wormcammina_9 = new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/slime9 copia.png");
    ImageView wormcammina9 = new ImageView(wormcammina_9);      

    wormcammina9.setFitHeight(150.0);
    wormcammina9.setFitWidth(200.0);
    wormcammina9.setLayoutX(90.0);
    wormcammina9.setLayoutY(90.0);
    wormcammina9.setPickOnBounds(true);
    wormcammina9.setPreserveRatio(true);
    wormcammina9.setVisible(true);

    Image wormcammina_10 = new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/slime10 copia.png");
    ImageView wormcammina10 = new ImageView(wormcammina_10);      

    wormcammina10.setFitHeight(150.0);
    wormcammina10.setFitWidth(200.0);
    wormcammina10.setLayoutX(99.0);
    wormcammina10.setLayoutY(99.0);
    wormcammina10.setPickOnBounds(true);
    wormcammina10.setPreserveRatio(true);
    wormcammina10.setVisible(true);

    Image raggioattakk1_1 = new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/raggioattak1 copia.png");
    ImageView  flashattacco1_1= new ImageView(raggioattakk1_1);

    flashattacco1_1.setFitHeight(150.0);
    flashattacco1_1.setFitWidth(200.0);
    flashattacco1_1.setPickOnBounds(true);
    flashattacco1_1.setPreserveRatio(true);
    flashattacco1_1.setVisible(true);

    Image wormprendidann= new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/slimeprendidanno.png");
    ImageView  wormprendidanno= new ImageView(wormprendidann);

    wormprendidanno.setFitHeight(113.0);
    wormprendidanno.setFitWidth(187.0);
    wormprendidanno.setLayoutX(568.0);
    wormprendidanno.setLayoutY(369.0);
    wormprendidanno.setPickOnBounds(true);
    wormprendidanno.setPreserveRatio(true);
    wormprendidanno.setVisible(true);

    Image warcammin= new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/warcamminaoriginalegif.gif");
    ImageView  warcammina= new ImageView(warcammin);

    warcammina.setFitHeight(150.0);
    warcammina.setFitWidth(200.0);
    warcammina.setPickOnBounds(true);
    warcammina.setPreserveRatio(true);
    warcammina.setVisible(true);        
    Rectangle veraposizioneworm = new Rectangle();
    Rectangle veraposizionewar = new Rectangle();      

    veraposizioneworm.setArcHeight(5.0);
    veraposizioneworm.setArcWidth(5.0);
    veraposizioneworm.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.DODGERBLUE);
    veraposizioneworm.setHeight(10.0);
    veraposizioneworm.setLayoutX(426.0);
    veraposizioneworm.setLayoutY(390.0);
    veraposizioneworm.setStroke(javafx.scene.paint.Color.BLACK);
    veraposizioneworm.setStrokeType(javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType.INSIDE);
    veraposizioneworm.setWidth(150.0);

    veraposizionewar.setArcHeight(5.0);
    veraposizionewar.setArcWidth(5.0);
    veraposizionewar.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.valueOf("#1f93ff"));
    veraposizionewar.setHeight(10.0);
    veraposizionewar.setLayoutX(496.0);
    veraposizionewar.setLayoutY(451.0);
    veraposizionewar.setStroke(javafx.scene.paint.Color.BLACK);
    veraposizionewar.setStrokeType(javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType.INSIDE);
    veraposizionewar.setWidth(20.0);

    Image raggioattakk1_2= new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/raggioattak2 copia.png");
    ImageView  flashattacco1_2= new ImageView(raggioattakk1_2);

    flashattacco1_2.setFitHeight(150.0);
    flashattacco1_2.setFitWidth(200.0);
    flashattacco1_2.setPickOnBounds(true);
    flashattacco1_2.setPreserveRatio(true);
    flashattacco1_2.setVisible(true);

    Image fl3= new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/raggioattak3 copia.png");
    ImageView  flashattacco1_3= new ImageView(fl3);

    flashattacco1_3.setFitHeight(150.0);
    flashattacco1_3.setFitWidth(200.0);
    flashattacco1_3.setPickOnBounds(true);
    flashattacco1_3.setPreserveRatio(true);
    flashattacco1_3.setVisible(true);

    Image warshoo7= new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/war7 copia.png");
    ImageView  warshoot7= new ImageView(warshoo7);

    warshoot7.setFitHeight(150.0);
    warshoot7.setFitWidth(200.0);
    warshoot7.setPickOnBounds(true);
    warshoot7.setPreserveRatio(true);
    warshoot7.setVisible(true);    

    Image warshoo6= new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/war6_5 copia.png");
    ImageView  warshoot6= new ImageView(warshoo6);

    warshoot6.setFitHeight(150.0);
    warshoot6.setFitWidth(200.0);
    warshoot6.setPickOnBounds(true);
    warshoot6.setPreserveRatio(true);
    warshoot6.setVisible(true);      

    Image warshoo5= new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/war6 copia.png");
    ImageView  warshoot5= new ImageView(warshoo5);

    warshoot5.setFitHeight(150.0);
    warshoot5.setFitWidth(200.0);
    warshoot5.setPickOnBounds(true);
    warshoot5.setPreserveRatio(true);
    warshoot5.setVisible(true);

    Image warshoo4= new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/war5 copia.png");
    ImageView  warshoot4= new ImageView(warshoo4);

    warshoot4.setFitHeight(150.0);
    warshoot4.setFitWidth(200.0);
    warshoot4.setPickOnBounds(true);
    warshoot4.setPreserveRatio(true);
    warshoot4.setVisible(true);

    Image warshoo3= new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/war4 copia.png");
    ImageView  warshoot3= new ImageView(warshoo3);

    warshoot3.setFitHeight(150.0);
    warshoot3.setFitWidth(200.0);
    warshoot3.setPickOnBounds(true);
    warshoot3.setPreserveRatio(true);
    warshoot3.setVisible(true);

    Image warshoo2= new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/war3 copia.png");
    ImageView  warshoot2= new ImageView(warshoo2);
    warshoot2.setFitHeight(150.0);
    warshoot2.setFitWidth(200.0);
    warshoot2.setPickOnBounds(true);
    warshoot2.setPreserveRatio(true);
    warshoot2.setVisible(true);

    Image warshoo1= new Image("file:///C:/Users/lorys/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXprimoprogetto/src/javafxprimoprogetto/war2 copia.png");
    ImageView  warshoot1= new ImageView(warshoo1);

    warshoot1.setFitHeight(150.0);
    warshoot1.setFitWidth(200.0);
    warshoot1.setPickOnBounds(true);
    warshoot1.setPreserveRatio(true);
    warshoot1.setVisible(true);

    //anchorpane occhio alle posizioni dei figli
    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
    root.getChildren().addAll(castle,warfermo,slimefermo,wormcammina1,wormcammina2,wormcammina3,wormcammina4,wormcammina5
            ,wormcammina6,wormcammina7,wormcammina8,wormcammina9,wormcammina10,flashattacco1_1);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1600, 900);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}   }
```

Comment: Post the *complete* stack trace as text in the question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: sorry, how i can do stack trace in a text file?

Comment: aaand.... today it happened something strange. i have no touched anything on my pc and... it work! after i tried for days. after i've read your message, export in netbean and work!...pc has not been turned off  and i just used it for something else. But with eclipse i got this message:  Warning loading FXML document with javafx API of version 8.0.111 by javafx runtime 8.0.101